# List not updating from Outlook to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

Ive got a SharePoint contact list which I have synchronised with users Outlook. When someone adds an entry to the list within Outlook it doesn't replicate if they manually add the contact to the list within SharePoint it updates their local Outlook contact list - any thoughts why this is happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot your issue as below:

1. Create a new contact list and sync to outlook, check if the new contact created in Outlook synced to SharePoint.
2. If the issue exists, In the Outlook->FILE->Options->Trust center->Trust Center settings->Privacy Options, make sure the “Allow Office to connect to the Internet”.
3. Then repair the Outlook client: [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
4. If only in this contact list, check if there is any filter in the list view.